# How to Filter ADO.NET data using a Full Text Search (FTS) field?

Tags: ado.net, full-text-search, sql-like

We are using ADO.NET dataservices & are building URL based filters.
Example: /Customers?filter=City eq 'London'

We now need to filter on a Full Text 'tags' Field.
WAS HOPING FOR: /Customers?filter=Tag like 'Friendly'

PROBLEM:
ADO.NET does not have a LIKE operator.
ADO.NET does not seem to like FTS
(It is not finding a match - because it is not parsing through the CSV's)

Any ideas how to make this work?
THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.NET Data Services do support "LIKE" kind of operator.

Queries like this:

```
http://localhost/EntitiesService.svc/CalEvents?$filter=indexof(Subject,'fO') ge 0

http://localhost/EntitiesService.svc/CalEvents?$filter=substringof('fox',Subject) eq true
```

or LINQ version:

```
 var result  = _context.CalEvents.Where(ce => ce.Subject.Contains(searchTerm))
```

Do probably what you looking for. They generate a SQL query with "LIKE" operator and add "%" to the search term. So, they act like "LIKE" operator.

FTS with "Contains" operator for example .. is not supported, I do not have time to check for sure but I think I saw it not so long ago.

More information:
http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with ADO.NET Data Services per se, but, when working with Full Text Search, I have found that the CONTAINS operator is much more powerful.  Whether in an ad hoc sql string, or in a stored proc.